# WSO2 API Manager Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Using WSO2 API Manager (V1.10), I published a API  and I imported the SSL certificate to *client-truststore.jks*. But When I call this API, I 'm receving this error:

```
2016-07-11 11:42:11,296 [-] [HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7] ERROR TargetHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1650)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1618)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1787)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1071)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:893)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:767)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:228)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:263)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:391)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: what did you mean by imported the certificate to client-truststore.jks? Does your API have different SSL certificate? in this case you have to import certificate in to client-trustore and wso2carbon.jks then use the certificate in the client you are using to call the API. Also please check the hostname in the certificate. This exception can occur because of the difference of hostname in certificate and request URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your API calling client program does not have the API server's certificate. (Usually you import your certificate into your JRE's jacerts or other trust store)

```
But When I call this API, I 'm receving this error:
```

When you call this API, did this API calling client program (Java, for example) also get this WSO2 server's certificate imported? This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error log this happens in http sender. i.e when api manger invokes the back-end . if your backend  is "HTTPS" you need to import its public certificate to trustore of APIM

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue in `Java 1.7`. `Java 1.8` has resolved my problem